# Run points() after plot() on a dataframe

Tags: r, plot

I'm new to R and want to plot specific points over an existing plot. I'm using the `swiss` data frame, which I visualize through the `plot(swiss)` function. [image]
After this, want to add outliers given by the Mahalanobis distance:

```
mu_hat <- apply(swiss, 2, mean); sigma_hat <- cov(swiss)
mahalanobis_distance <- mahalanobis(swiss, mu_hat, sigma_hat) 
outliers <- swiss[names(mahalanobis_distance[mahalanobis_distance > 10]),]
points(outliers, pch = 'x', col = 'red')
```

but this last line has no effect, as the outlier points aren't added to the previous plot. I see that if repeat this procedure on a pair of variables, say

```
plot(swiss[2:3])
points(outliers[2:3], pch = 'x', col = 'red')
```

the red points are added to the plot. 
[image]
Ask: is there any restriction to how the `points()` function can be used for a multivariate data frame?

Comment: `points` can add points to the active plot. When you `plot` a data frame, you actually get an individual plot for each row-column combination - and you can't go backwards and edit the previous ones. For additional customization, I'd recommend using  `ggplot2`, specifically the add-on , `GGally::ggpairs`.

Comment: @Gregor as far as I can tell this isn't a duplicate. Maybe you should put your comment as an answer?

Comment: Please make the problem reproducible by including values for mu_hat and sigma_hat.

Comment: My comment works as an answer to "can I use the points function to modify the plots produced by `plot.df`", but it's not a full answer to the implied real question of "how can I generate a pairs plot with outliers in a different color". neilfws's answer looks great to me.

Answer (score 2):

Here's a solution using `GGally::ggpairs`. It's a little ugly as we need to modify the `ggally_points` function to specify the desired color scheme.

I've assumed that `mu_hat = colMeans(swiss)` and `sigma_hat = cov(swiss)`.

```
library(dplyr)
library(GGally)

swiss %>% 
  bind_cols(distance = mahalanobis(swiss, colMeans(swiss), cov(swiss))) %>%
  mutate(is_outlier = ifelse(distance > 10, "yes", "no")) %>%
  ggpairs(columns = 1:6, 
          mapping = aes(color = is_outlier), 
          upper = list(continuous = function(data, mapping, ...) {
            ggally_points(data = data, mapping = mapping) +
              scale_colour_manual(values = c("black", "red"))
          }), 
          lower = list(continuous = function(data, mapping, ...) {
            ggally_points(data = data, mapping = mapping) + 
              scale_colour_manual(values = c("black", "red"))
          }),
          axisLabels = "internal")
```

[image]

Answer (score -1):

Unfortunately this isn't possible the way you're currently doing things. When plotting a data frame R produces many plots and aligns them. What you're actually seeing there is 6 by 6 = 36 individual plots which have all been aligned to look nice.

When you use the `dots` command, it tells it to place the dots on the current plot. Which doesn't really make sense when you have 36 plots, at least not the way you want it to.

`ggplot` is a really powerful tool in R, it provides far greater combustibility. For example you could set up the dataframe to include your outliers, but have them labelled as "outlier" and place it in each plot that you have set up as facets. The more you explore it you might find there are better plots which suit your needs as well.

Plotting a dataframe in base R is a good exploratory tool. You could set up those outliers as a separate dataframe and plot it, so you can see each of the 6 by 6 plots side by side and compare. It all depends on your goal. If you're goal is to produce exactly as you've described, the `ggplot2` package will help you create something more professional. As @Gregor suggested in the comments, looking up the function `ggpairs` from the `GGally` package would be a good place to start.

A quick google image search shows some funky plots akin to what you're after and then some!
[image]

[Find it here](https://www.r-bloggers.com/building-a-dga-classifer-part-2-feature-engineering/)